# How to remove all data attributes on element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been checking many and many posts here in stackoverflow but, even if many solutions should be working, it yet doesn't work for me.

I have a modal in bootstrap where I have a list of bootstrap checkboxes (`<label><input>` style).

Each checkbox has a set of data attributes that **are directly setted from an AJAX request** and, therefore, that aren't settet through jQuery.

In my situation, I need to remove all the data-attr from the checkbox when it is toggled and add some other.

The problem, however, is that I'm being unable to remove them.

I've first tried using `jQuery.removeData()`, but then I've read that it actually **only removes data attributes if at least one of them has been set through jQuery**, therefore it is not my case.

So, I've checked a little bit around and found out that I should be using `jQuery.removeAttr()` prototype and remove each data element.

So, my case is this one:

```
$('.modal_day_checkbox').on('change', function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            removeAllData($(this));
            $(this).data('newid', 'test_id');
            console.log($(this).data());
        }
        else {
            removeAllData($(this));
            $(this).data('testID', 'ID_NEW');
            console.log($(this).data());
        }
    });
```

And, in order to have a clean code, I've implemented the function removeAllData:

```
function removeAllData(object) {
        $.each(object.data(), function(i, v) {
            object.removeAttr("data-"+i);
            console.log('removing: '+'data-'+i);
        });
    }
```

Which is just looping through the object to check what data attributes it has and it should be removing it.

Surprisingly, the result is this one:

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: If someone is still reading the question, the solution is, as proposed by @Alnitak, to replace .removeAttr with .removeData, providing the index [i] of the each loop!

Comment: according to the docs you would use the _name_ of the data, not its index.  And actually I was just proposing that you both call your own function _and_ `object.removeData()` to ensure that both the cache _and_ the HTML attributes are removed.

Comment: It the data attributes are, as you said, not added by jQuery, why would you need `removeData`, which removes data from the internal jQuery data object ?

Comment: Ah, the index being referred to was actually a key, not a number.  That works, but you can just call `.removeData()` with no keys and get them all in one go.

Comment: @adeneo in my experience, any _access_ to the `data` attributes causes the cache to be created, it's not just creation that does this.

Comment: @adeneo: from what I've read, if you use $('#anyelement').removeData(); it is supposed to remove all the data elements, if at least one of them has been added through jQuery. .removeData(), however, removes a data-element if you know the exact attribute name. In my case, however, I don't know the data-attribute names, as they are setted dinamically.

Comment: @briosheje - `removeData` removes the data in the internal data object, not the attributes.

Comment: @Alnitak - any use of `data` probably does, but not `attr`

Comment: @adeneo indeed - that's what I meant :)  Experiments here suggest that once a cache has been created and removed, it won't get automatically re-filled with every data value, but will be filled if you ask for a specific piece of data.

Comment: @adeneo: I didn't know it wasn't removing the attr, thanks for pointing that out :P In any case I just need to work with object itself later, therefore I shouldn't have any issue!

Comment: @briosheje - Then you should be setting the value to `null` or `undefined`, and generally not remove the data with `removeData`

Comment: @adeneo: even if, later, I have to loop through all the elements of the object? having them undefined mean looping more, right?

Comment: It's generally as easy as `$.each(Object.keys(obj.data()), function(_, d) { obj.data(d, null) });`, but I think you're trying to solve something that shouldn't really be an issue to begin with ?

Comment: @adeneo: Yes, that's the case :P Thanks for the tips anyway, It's always nice to read different solutions and considerations about the main problem :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try calling the jQuery `.removeData` function as well as your `removeAllData` function:

```
function removeAllData(object) {
    $.each(object.data(), function(i, v) {
        object.removeAttr("data-"+i);
        console.log('removing: '+'data-'+i);
    });
    object.removeData();  // clear the cache too
}
```

jQuery maintains a separate object where `data-foo` values are cached as soon as they're access (and where *writes* to `.data` are stored) and that cache is not cleared when you call `.removeAttr('data-foo')`.

Comment: You mean that I should replace .removeAttr with .removeData?

Comment: Yes, but don't append the `data-` prefix. Just `object.removeData(i)`

Comment: Indeed, tried it and actually works.. Damn, I was so close :P Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as the system allows me to, I have to wait 8 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

Chosen solution works great, but will break on multi-dash attributes (like `data-one-two`) because:

> Since jQuery 3, every two-character sequence of "-" (U+002D) followed
>   by a lowercase ASCII letter in a key is replaced by the uppercase
>   version of the letter, in alignment with the HTML dataset API. A
>   statement like `$( "body" ).data( { "my-name": "aValue" } ).data();`
>   will return `{ myName: "aValue" }`.

[source](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

To make results of `data()` work with `removeAttr()` we should cast them back to normal:

```
function removeAllData(object) {
    $.each(object.data(), function(i, v) {
        i = i.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function(all, letter) {
            return '-' + letter.toLowerCase()
        });  // fix multi-dash attributes
        object.removeAttr("data-"+i);
        console.log('removing: '+'data-'+i);
    });
    object.removeData();  // clear the cache too
}
```

It's not an ideal solution, but should work in most cases.

Answer (score -1):

this is wrong

```
object.removeAttr("data-"+i);
```

// you have to pass in the name of the attribute

Do this instead

```
 $.each(object.data(), function(i, v) {
            object.removeAttr(v);
            console.log('removing: '+v);
        });
```

// Removed quote

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't work. It throws me an Uncaught InvalidCharacterError. Thanks for downvoting both the question and the answer above anyway