# how to remove all data attributes from all instances of a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to remove **all** `data` attributes from `.title`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.title').removeAttr('data');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-w = 960 data-x = 'gold'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-w = 540 data-x = 'silver'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-w = 720 data-x = 'sun'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Doesn't work. Another try:

```
$('.title').removeAttr('data-w', 'data-x');
```

Removes only the first one (`data-w`)

Any help?

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/25063664/10068463, but also know that `removeAttr()` only accepts 1 attribute name, so you have to call it for every attribute you want to remove (which the related post tells you how to do for all data attributes on the element).

Comment: If those `data-*` attributes created dinamically you can use `$(".title").removeData()`

Comment: I'm surprised - there is no a native jq function for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

```
       $("#button").click(function(){
            $(".title").each(function() {                       
                var titleElement = $(this);
                $.each(titleElement.data(), function(i){
                    titleElement.removeAttr('data-'+i);
                });
            }); 
        });
```

I have tested it and it is working fine. 
Check working example: https://codepen.io/rohitmittal/pen/WPdKzj

Comment: Can you please attach a link to the fiddle or pen, or maybe add a stack snippet here, so that I can visualize how it works?

Answer (score 2):

You can get all the `keys` from data and then remove `data-key`.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var keys = Object.keys($("div").data());
  keys.forEach(key =>{
    $('.title').removeAttr(`data-${key}`);
  })
  console.log(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.title')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-w = 960 data-x = 'gold'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-w = 540 data-x = 'silver'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-w = 720 data-x = 'sun'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to accomplish that:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var titleClasses = $('.title');
  titleClasses.each(function() {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-x')
    .removeAttr('data-w');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='title' data-w=9 60 data-x='gold'>lorem</div>
<div class='title' data-w=5 40 data-x='silver'>ipsum</div>
<div class='title' data-w=7 20 data-x='sun'>lorem</div>
<br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: `$('.title').removeAttr('data-x').removeAttr('data-w')`; - shorter but what if I have a lot of them

Comment: then I think the answer suggested by @Maheer Ali is the best one I have seen so far. Its generic